# "Mirror pod not available" errors - kubernetes HA setup

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I have a multi-master kubernetes v1.1.3 setup. I use the hyperkube binary to run kubelet on the master and have the scheduler and controller manager running in pods with the podmaster acting as the elector. The master's are loadbalanced using HAproxy, and the kubelet on the minions uses that loadbalanced IP as their apiserver endpoint. I am using docker v1.8.2.

I am not having any errors in use, I can deploy pods that are running without issue across the minions and everything *seems* happy.

However, I am getting constant error spam (every 10 seconds) from the kubelet on the master:

```
[err] [kubelet] E0201 21:10:54 kubelet.go:1361] Mirror pod not available
[err] [kubelet] E0201 21:10:54 kubelet.go:1361] Mirror pod not available
[err] [kubelet] E0201 21:10:54 kubelet.go:1361] Mirror pod not available
[err] [kubelet] E0201 21:10:54 kubelet.go:1361] Mirror pod not available
[err] [kubelet] E0201 21:11:04 kubelet.go:1361] Mirror pod not available
```

I am concerned that this is symptomatic of something set up improperly that I am missing. Is this anything to be concerned of? If not, is there anything I could configure to silence the error spam?

*edit*: here are the options I am running kubelet with:

kubelet on master (mostly standard):

```
hyperkube kubelet --v=2 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --kubeconfig=<path-to-config> --port=10250 --address=0.0.0.0 --cadvisor-port=4194 --allow-privileged=true
```

all pod manifests: http://pastebin.com/MJfQz78r

Comment: I've seen the same problem "Mirror pod not available" (tested version 1.1.4), but I haven't been able to start cluster properly. Can you publish your configs (manifests) please?

Comment: I edited to show how I am running kubelet and then made a pastebin with my pod manifests. I am not running etcd in pods. it is running on separate nodes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be something related to deprecated feature static pod - http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/static-pods.html

Source code - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.1.4/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L1361

IMHO you can ignore it. I didn't find this feature in 1.2alpha7 source code. Maybe you can decrease your log level `--v=0` https://github.com/golang/glog

Thank you for your manifests.